# Is it possible to ensure that threaded code doesn't have side effects in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

[Data safety and GIL removal](http://merbist.com/2011/10/18/data-safety-and-gil-removal/) mentions that if you don't have the Giant Interpreter Lock in place, you increase the risk of race conditions. The blog post gave the following example:

```
# As noted in the blog post, this'll work correctly in MRI Ruby (1.8 or 1.9)
# but may or may not work correctly in Rubinius 2.0 or JRuby
@array, threads = [], []
4.times do
  threads << Thread.new { (1..100_000).each {|n| @array << n} }
end
threads.each{|t| t.join }
puts @array.size
```

One approach I'd take to making the code thread safe is to do functional programming and not have code within the thread modify objects/variables that weren't created within the thread:

```
threads = 4.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    sub_array = []
    # Modifying sub_array is fine, because it was created by this thread
    (1..100_000).each {|n| sub_array << n}
    sub_array
  end
end
puts threads.map(&:value).flatten(1).size
# Or (and don't forget nil!)
# array = threads.map(&:value).flatten(1) ; nil
# puts array.size
```

Is it possible to specify that a thread isn't allowed to modify objects/variables that don't "belong" to it, and raise a warning or exception if it does?

Assume that the threaded code doesn't do anything spectacularly pathological like calling `ObjectSpace.each_object`.

Comment: "GIL" means "Global Interpreter Lock", not "Giant Interpreter Lock" although I think your *interpretation* is more amusing.

Comment: @tadman: I can't claim credit for the cromulent term: it currently has 2390 google hits (versus 117K google hits for "Global Interpreter Lock").

Comment: Actually, YARV calls it the GVL (Giant VM Lock), I think. GIL is what CPython calls it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to limit Ruby's access to things in any capacity other than the long-standing tradition of forking out a new process that is independent. Most languages are like this with very few exceptions, with strictly functional languages being in that set as you point out.

The most responsible approach here is to either use Mutex locking, or to create classes that are thread-safe by keeping data isolated and independent. This requires careful design, but if done right your threaded application is nearly as simple as a standard one.

Comment: "Most languages are like this ..." - is it because it's hard to implement, or because there's little "demand" for it?

Comment: It's because it implies programmers need to be protected from themselves on some level, and no matter the intentions, that comes across as developer-hostile. The best approach is to avoid sharing references to the same data so you're not tempted to use it in more than one thread.